# How to activate Key Press Event, in Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Here is my Code. I want to capture a pressed key and print it.  But Nothing will Happen, How to resolve it? I Have two classes. One is Create_Instance and another one is Main_Window. In My code, I have Only Lable items  to display. How to activate it?

**Edited**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Create_Instance(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,dict_item):
        super().__init__()

        self.dict_items = dict_item
        self.lbl = QLabel("This is My Label")
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(event)
        print(self.dict_items)

class Main_Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
        self.layout_main = QHBoxLayout()

        self.firstmenu_container = Create_Instance(dict_item="1")
        self.secondmenu_container = Create_Instance(dict_item="2")
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.firstmenu_container)
        self.layout_main.addWidget(self.secondmenu_container)

        self.setLayout(self.layout_main)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main_Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Key events can only be caught if the widget has input focus, and only *one* widget at a time can have input focus. Either add `self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)` to the `__init__` of `Create_Instance` or override the `keyPressEvent` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the widget to the layout:

```py
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle("Main Window")
    self.layout_main = QHBoxLayout()

    self.firstmenu_container = Create_Instance(dict_item="1")
    self.layout_main.addWidget(self.firstmenu_container)
    self.secondmenu_container = Create_Instance(dict_item="2")
    self.layout_main.addWidget(self.secondmenu_container)

    self.setLayout(self.layout_main)
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not working for me. any other ides

Comment: This won't solve the issue. The widget must have input focus (or, at least, be the *active* top level window) to receive keyboard events.